# Requisitos para preguntas sobre el origen de expresiones

Tags: discusión, preguntas

La reciente pregunta *[¿Cuál es el origen de la frase “autolike para no desaparecer”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31130/12637)*, cerrada a partes iguales por los motivos "offtopic" y "unclear what you're asking", me genera una duda.

En muchas ocasiones se ha preguntado por los orígenes de determinadas expresiones. Entiendo que dichas expresiones deben cumplir una serie de requisitos para que se admita como pregunta válida acerca del idioma español, pero ¿cuáles? ¿Que sea una expresión conocida al menos en determinados ámbitos geográficos? ¿Que aparezca en el diccionario? ¿Que se pueda encontrar documentada en el CORDE o el CREA o en la hemeroteca? ¿O en un número suficiente de páginas de Internet? ¿Que tenga un significado diferente del que se supondría según los significados de las palabras individuales?

En la pregunta enlazada se pregunta el origen de una expresión muy reciente que no sé si cumple alguno de estos requisitos. El autor de la pregunta considera que la frase es un meme de Internet, y la ha visto en varios sitios diferentes. No considera que tenga un significado metafórico aparte del literal, pero no le encaja con el funcionamiento de los sitios donde aparece ([recientes descubrimientos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51259572#51259572) indican que podría esconder más de lo que parece). También considera que la frase-meme tiene su origen en el idioma español, que no es ninguna traducción de la misma frase en otros idiomas.

El problema de los memes es que son fugaces y en su inmensa mayoría no generan expresiones que lleguen a incorporarse al idioma. Aun así, en este caso se desea saber el origen de una expresión. ¿Qué argumentos existen para mantener la pregunta cerrada? ¿Qué la diferencia exactamente de preguntar el origen de "partir la pana"? ¿Qué requisitos debe cumplir una pregunta sobre el origen de una expresión para ser considerada válida?

Answer (score 3):

Cuando revisé la pregunta, lo cierto es que me echó un poco para atrás, porque no es una expresión que haya escuchado ni leído nunca, y de primeras parecía más un simple calco del inglés que otra cosa.
No obstante, que yo no conozca la respuesta, no quiere decir que la pregunta no sea válida. Mi criterio es:

- **Es una frase en español** ✔
  Está claro que "autolike para no desaparecer" es español.
- **Se está usando en un contexto hispanoparlante** ✔
  Por las explicaciones que da OP, parece una frase usada por personas que hablan en español. No es una frase suelta mal traducida por alguien que no conoce el idioma.
- **Puede haber dudas legítimas sobre el significado o sobre el origen de la expresión** ✔
  En este caso, OP explica que no ha podido investigar su origen a partir de un supuesto equivalente en inglés *"autolike to not disappear"*. Esto es normal, puesto que en "autolike", el prefijo *auto-* tiene un significado típico español de "uno/a mismo/a" (autoinfligido, autoservicio) que en inglés se indica con *self-*, no con *auto-* (*self-inflicted*, *self-service*). Esto es una señal clara de que la expresión ha sido acuñada por hispanohablantes, y por tanto es legítimo preguntar su origen y quizá su significado. Porque ¿quién me dice a mí que la expresión no se está usando con otro sentido, quizá irónico, como queriendo decir "me tengo que dar *like* yo mismo porque no tengo éxito"?

Creo que el cierre de la pregunta pudo venir motivado en parte por el desconocimiento de la expresión, y en parte porque estaba redactada de manera que parecía que OP preguntaba sobre el origen del ¿bulo? de que las publicaciones desaparecen si no tienen *likes*, más que sobre el origen de la expresión en sí. Sin embargo, centrándome en la pregunta que se hacía en el título, creo que era válida aplicando los criterios descritos.

Comment: Ciertamente, tras la conversación mantenida con Obie opino igual que tú, y espero haber aprendido algo tras la experiencia. Aunque de momento parece que la pregunta tiene dos votos para reabrirse y otros dos para mantenerse cerrada...

Comment: Si "autolike" se interpreta como "like automático", que es lo común en inglés, se puede hallar usos como [este](https://www.autolikesfree.net/).  Claro que "automático" o "automatic" en inglés, contiene ese mismo prefijo griego.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo comentado