# Incluyamos las preguntas sobre expresiones al tipo de preguntas admitidas en el Help Center

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, ámbito, centro-de-ayuda

Para poneros en contexto, hoy he entrado y me he encontrado en la cola de revisión el voto de reapertura de la siguiente pregunta: [¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "autolike para no desaparecer"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31130/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-origen-de-la-frase-autolike-para-no-desaparecer)

Yo fui uno de los que votó que se cerrara la pregunta, ya que no la consigo clasificar en ninguna de estas preguntas: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Al revisar los comentarios de la pregunta me encontré con que ya se discutió sobre el caso de esta pregunta en meta: [Requisitos para preguntas sobre el origen de expresiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/requisitos-para-preguntas-sobre-el-origen-de-expresiones)

Y tras leerlo puedo ver que la pregunta se podría reabrir dado que hay precedentes de preguntas sobre el origen de **expresiones** en español que se han considerado on-topic.

Ahora la **pregunta** en sí: ¿Bajo qué categoría de preguntas on-topic caen las preguntas sobre el origen de expresiones en español?

---

Estas son las categorías que hay ahora mismo definidas como preguntas on-topic en [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) del Help Center:

> - Lingüística (fonética, fonología, morfología, sintaxis, semántica,
>     pragmática)
> - Ortografía (acentos, puntuación, guiones, mayúsculas)
> - Etimología (historia del desarrollo de las palabras)
> - Traducción de cierta expresión o concepto al español (pero recuerda que debes indicar qué has intentado)
> - Diferencias dialécticas
> - Usos, elección de palabras, gramática y pronunciación
> - Problemas encontrados por la gente que está aprendiendo español

Hay bastantes categorías muy obvias, como lingüistica, ortografía, diferencias dialécticas y problemas aprendiendo español.
En etimología no entra ya que trata de palabras, no expresiones;
no hablamos de traducciones de expresiones, sino del origen de expresiones propias de la lengua;
y en usos y elección de palabras no termino de verlo encajar, ya que para estas expresiones buscamos que su significado no sea el significado literal de las palabras;

Comment: @walen yo propondría incluso añadir el origen de las expresiones a la categoría de "etimología", y poner algo así como "Etimología de las palabras y origen de las expresiones". Me parece bien el cambio, preguntar por el origen de las expresiones en español creo que es muy on-topic. Proponed vuestros cambios y en una semana ponemos lo más votado. Si no os parece on-topic, proponedlo también y se votará igualmente.

Comment: @walen - Gracias, no sabía.  Voy a hacer un rollback.

Comment: @walen - Gracias, pero prefiero el rollback.  Traté de aplicar el principio de no entrar a editar un post si mi *edit* no *mejora* el texto o la presentación.  Si hubiera editado otras cosas -- sería diferente.  Pero no encontré nada más que editar.  Así que no debería haberlo tocado.

Answer (score 1):

#### Propuesta de cambio

Sustituir "palabras" por "palabras y expresiones" en la lista de temas *on-topic*.

Concretamente:

- desarrollo de las palabras → desarrollo de las palabras y expresiones
- elección de palabras → elección de palabras y expresiones

Answer (score 0):

**Propuesta de cambio.**

Cambiar:

> Etimología (historia del desarrollo de las palabras).
>   Usos, elección de palabras, gramática y pronunciación

Por:

> Etimología de las palabras y origen de las expresiones.
>   Usos y elección de palabras y expresiones, gramática y pronunciación.

Comment: @walen ¿mejor así?

Answer (score 0):

**Propuesta de cambio.**

Añadir nuevo punto a las preguntas on-topic:

- origen y/o significado de expresiones comunes cuyo significado no parece reflejar el significado literal de las palabras que las compone.